# flutter local notification display only the last notification in tray

Tags: flutter, firebase-cloud-messaging, tray, flutter-local-notification

in my flutter project, I used FCM to push notifications and flutter_local_notification to display the received notifications
and I used the "data" payload to read the notification in my app.
and it works fine, but when I send more than one notification only the last one appears in the device tray (For both ios & android).
it seems like the application received only one notification

anything to do so multi notifications could be shown in the tray

Comment: maybe notification id same every time?

Comment: that's right. Thank you !!